# What's the relationship between $p(X)p(Y)$ and $p(X,Y)$

Tags: probability

If $X,Y$ are random variables, and not necessarily independent, then what's the relationship between  $p(X)p(Y)$ and $p(X,Y)$? $p$ is probability density function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that can be said about this is
$$p(X|Y)p(Y)=p(X,Y)$$

Independence between $X$ and $Y$ means that $p(X|Y)=p(X)$, but without the independence condition, $p(X|Y)$ can be anything.

Comment: What exactly is $p(X\mid Y)$ intended to denote?

Comment: p(X|y) is p(X) given Y. 
Meaning, given that a specific event Y = y has happened, then what is the probability that X will take various values. If X and Y are not independent than Y = y would exclude certain events (i.e., where Y != y), this will change the probability distribution of X